# How to handle cascade delete in presistancejs lib?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how to handle cascade delete in presistencejs lib.
[presistencejs site](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling I think that no way to do this automatically and I had to do it manually